# Adding a native libary to eclipse project which has further dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, java.library.path

My goal is to add a native library to an eclipse project which has further dependencies on DLLs which are usually part of Windows OS or the MS Visual Studio redistributables (e.g., MSVCR110.dll and others...).

Putting my native library foo.dll in a Java-Project A source folder works for Project A alone (w/o any build-path adjustments).

But as soon as another Java-Project B references and uses project A, I get for Project B the error "UnsatisfiedLinkError: no foo.dll in java.library.path".

I get past this error by adding the location to foo.dll in the eclipse java build path of Project B --> tab "source --> edit "Native library location: ".

This however, results in the error "UnsatisfiedLinkError: Project A/foo.dll: Can't find dependent libraries" - which I guess are the above mentioned system-libraries, which are obviously not located in the folder of Project A, but in some system-folder...

Any solution to that?